# Xcode: Release app update for iPhone only?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I have made an app for both iPhone and iPad in the past, but the latest update it only intended for iPhone.

I switched `Target Device Family` to `iPhone Only` and archived and validated, but I get the error:

```
"This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version"
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why can't you also release it for iPad (leaves you only one version to support)

Comment: Dupe. You simply cannot, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is original a universal app, so all subsequent updates must also be universal.

There is nothing you can do in order to separate the update between iPhone and iPad - your app is one app.

The simple fact is that iPad users will receive an update, and nothing will change, while iPhone users will notice the differences.

This isn't an uncommon thing - it happens all the time. The answer is to not worry about it. Fix whatever you need to fix, submit the updated the app and be on your merry way.

Comment: It's possible I misunderstood your question. Do you mean that the new app no longer runs on iPad anymore, not just that the update only applies to the iPhone version and leaves the iPad version untouched?

Comment: Also, it's the exact same application bundle that runs on iPhone and iPad.  And you can only have one application bundle on the app store at once for an app.  That's why you can't release only an update for iPhone.  You update the universal app, even if the update only contain stuff for one platform.

Comment: "so all subsequent updates must also be universal." Where does it say this?

Comment: It doesn't "say it" anywhere, but when an application is uploaded to iTunes Connect, the pre-review checks will reject the binary because it was expecting a universal binary. This is the error the original poster was asking about: "This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version".